# How to make PHP (in MS4W Apache) setting for MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, ms4w

I am new for MSSQL. I wanted to make php setting for MSSQL. What i mean by that is to avoid following error while trying to establish connection using PHP and MSSQL

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()**

. I thing i have to establish setting in **php.ini** but i am not able to do that. can any one please help me out how to do this PHP and MSSQL extension activated. I have uncommented the extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll in php.ini but did not worked. Please guide me to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Refer: http://www.davidlauzon.net/2009/02/ms-sql-server-2008-with-php/. and do as needed. My problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm registered had this type of problem with WampServer,

In my case I had to go edit the file directly in the folder (with wamp :'C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\php.ini'), because when I accessed to php.ini via the interface (and after restart all services) nothing changed. The image below shows that the two files are different (but I do not know why):

[image]

at the left the file is still commented after a restart.

It's therefore necessary to modify the correct php.ini file and restart all services,

I hope it will be useful,

Comment: in my php.ini file this extension  is not there. even i have put that one in php.ini. but this dll in not there.

Comment: ok, I have got PHP 5.3, what's your version of PHP?

Comment: even mine is PHP 5.3.6

Comment: you can then download the correct *.dll (check the version for 5.3.6) and copy this file in the "ext" folder (in your PHP folder). Then try to restart your server with uncomment lines.

Comment: i have done that too.